# how to filter out notification sounds from ringtone sounds in android ringtone preference?

Tags: android, android-notifications

In my app I have just built in a ringtone preference so that the user can select what type of sound they would like to receive when they get notifications, however the problem Im running into here is that the list that is presented gives both ringtone for phone calls and notification sounds for messengers etc, I want just the notification sounds for messengers, If a user selects a ringtone for a phone call my app could become very annoying very fast. Is there a way to filter the notification sounds from the ringtone sounds? I see other apps doing this but Im unable to find a way to do it online, any help would be massive thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Filter the list by chossing only audio which is a notification sound. When you query for audio files, you would need to check it in the where clause that : MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.IS_NOTIFICATION is non-zero ( and all other fields such as IS_ALARM is zero). You will find more info about the table colums i am referring to  here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.html

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out, for ringtone type in the xml I had it set to all, I simply changed it to `android:ringtoneType="notification"` and that solved it, there also other ringtone types for alarm and all of that, hope this helps someone else who encounters the same problem!